# IS ES7 another name for ECMAScript2016? How to write it in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecma

Can somebody please **help me understand the versions of ECMAScript**. **I need to make a React JS App using ES7.** Now searching in internet there is hell lot of confusion. There is a ES5 version,and then there is EcmaScript2015 which is same as ES6 (I suppose) . **So is ES7 another name for ECMAScript2016?**
Searching everywhere i only found that react can be written in ES5(createClass) and ES6(class). Are there any syntax differences in ES7?

Comment: You are right, ES2016 is the seventh edition of EcmaScript. Unfortunately many people tend to use ES7 to refer to any (possible) JavaScript feature newer the ES2015. So I'm afraid you have to ask that person what exactly is meant by ES7.

Comment: If you read the [tag:ecmascript-7] tag description you will know what changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the relation between ES6, ES7 (and bigger), ES2015, stage-0, stage-1 (and bigger)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078527/what-is-the-relation-between-es6-es7-and-bigger-es2015-stage-0-stage-1-an/39078625)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ECMAScript 7** is old name for **ECMAScript 2016** according to the story written by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer

Please take a look to [A brief history of ECMAScript](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_about-es6.html#ecmascript-history)

- ECMAScript 1 (June 1997)
- ECMAScript 2 (June 1998)
- ECMAScript 3 (December 1999)
- ECMAScript 4 (abandoned in July 2008)
- ECMAScript 5 (December 2009)
- ECMAScript 5.1 (June 2011

And the best part - **ECMAScript 6 (June 2015)** history

- ECMAScript Harmony: was the initial code name for JavaScript improvements after ECMAScript 5.
- ECMAScript.next: It became apparent that the plans for Harmony were too ambitious for a single version, so its features were split into two groups: The first group of features had highest priority and was to become the next version after ES5. The code name of that version was ECMAScript.next, to avoid prematurely comitting to a version number, which proved problematic with ES4. The second group of features had time until after ECMAScript.next.
- ECMAScript 6: As ECMAScript.next matured, its code name was dropped and everybody started to call it ECMAScript 6.
- ECMAScript 2015: In late 2014, TC39 decided to change the official name of ECMAScript 6 to ECMAScript 2015, in light of upcoming yearly spec releases. However, given how established the name “ECMAScript 6” already is and how late TC39 changed their minds, I expect that that’s how everybody will continue to refer to that version.

And the grande finale

**ECMAScript 2016** was previously called **ECMAScript 7**. Starting with ES2016, the language standard will see smaller yearly releases.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that many people (incorrectly) mean something else when they say ES7. For them, every feature that is not ES2015 is ES7. Even if that feature is not part of any standard yet. Even worse: Some people refer to some upcoming features as ES6.

Comment: Thanks that was a beautiful explanation. So if i need to write a React App using ES7  it simply means I can use the later version that is ES6 syntax for it right?

Comment: @ShambhaviShah I think so. Depends how to count https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe - Is it ES2017?